# One To One mapping using @MapsId between multiple entities

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

[image]

I have 3 classes that have One To One association between them. Using hibernate, i'm trying to
map between these classes, by using @MapsId annotation as the following article states (which is by the way a great article): [OneToOne Best practices](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

But the problem is the examples given in the majority of articles i've found, only work with two entities, but not more (which is my case).

Using the @MapsId between Driver class and Destination class, if i create a new Driver, its identifier will be the same as the Destination's identifier; it will play the Role of a PK for Driver and a FK referencing Destination class.

But what about the Vehicule class, i can't use @MapsId between it and Driver, so what can i do to ensure the best mapping performance. Any suggestions ?

P.S: i know that i can have one class combining Destination and Vehicule info and that will solve the problem, but i need the classes to be separated since i want to do some CRUD operations on the 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I see what the problem is.

```
@Entity
public class Driver {
    @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

@Entity
public class Destination {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    Driver driver;

@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    Driver driver;
```

Which creates tables with a single key;

```
Hibernate: create table Destination (driver_id bigint not null, primary key (driver_id))
Hibernate: create table Driver (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Vehicle (driver_id bigint not null, primary key (driver_id))
Hibernate: alter table Destination add constraint FK1ndeqobn3ki4y7js6twsbn4kv foreign key (driver_id) references Driver
Hibernate: alter table Vehicle add constraint FKgoiw2f7ekq0ja5xtwpfnpxn47 foreign key (driver_id) references Driver
```

If you want to be careful with performance then you will need to stay away from bidirectional mappings. You can use them but be sure to dump the SQL so you are aware of what's going on. You can even map bidirectional associations between `Vehicle` and `Destination` but again Hibernate will generate all sorts of extra queries. Better IMHO to keep it simple and issue queries yourself for what you need.